# How to use react-document-meta in the React JS on server-side rendering?

Tags: reactjs, meta-tags, server-side-rendering

I am using react-document-meta, but I could not get through server side rendering.

I am following the example for the server side rendering, but it is not working.

I was creating the issue, but it is not helping me.

https://github.com/kodyl/react-document-meta/issues/45

My structure the app:

[image: my structure the app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed `renderAsHTML` to `renderAsReact` and it worked.